# How to nameref to partial part of a ref

Tags: cross-referencing

For example, I have :

```
\section {first section}
\label{sec:first}\
...
```

then I want to refer to the first section, I use it as below:

```
Please look at `\nameref{first}` for details.
```

I will get:

> Please look at first section for details.

But if I only want this (without section, only partial part of the reference):

> Please look at first for details.

How should I do to get it?

I guess a better example  would be:

```
\section{data.h File Description} 
\label{sec:datah}
....
Details are given in \nameref{datah}.
```

What I really want is:

> Details are given in data.h.

But I get:

> Details are given in data.h File Description.

I hope this example is clear enought. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you always use `\section{first section}` ... `\section{second section}` ... `\section{some section}`, or does it differ sometimes? Since the sections are numbered and the output is `1 First section`, you should consider just writing `\section{First}` which will output `1 First` and yield the appropriate `\nameref` you're after.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here it is only an example, not the real contents.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: `\nameref` is not a standard LaTeX command. Please provide a minal example.

Answer (score 7):

Since the required return from a `\nameref` might be anywhere inside the title of a `\section`, you can use `\labelname{<stuff>}` as defined below to update the reference text returned:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelname}[1]{% \labelname{<stuff>}
  \def\@currentlabelname{#1}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{\texttt{data.h} File Description}
\labelname{\texttt{data.h}}\label{sec:datah}% Overwrite title name/reference
Also see \nameref{sec:dataj}.

\section{File Description for \texttt{data.j}}
\label{sec:dataj}% Keep regular title reference
Details are given in \nameref{sec:datah}.
\end{document}
```

[`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) stores the name of the previous title in `\@currentlabelname`, which is overwritten using `\labelname`.

This is also compatible with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: The important thing is that \labelname comes before \label. The solution also does not change the label in the TOC. :thumbsup:

Comment: For me, only the `\def\@currentlabelname{value}` line was needed before the `\label`, the `makeat*` and including `nameref` might not be necessary in some cases.