# Remove two words

Tags: stringstrings

I'm writing a description of a method, where the title of each section is formatted like `Step X: <step title>`. Now, I want to reference the section as `Step X ("<step title>")`. I am aware of `\nameref`, but I don't know how to remove the first two words of a string.

When trying to use `stringstrings` to remove the first two words, I get

> Use of `\removeword` doesn't match its definition.

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\newcounter{step}

\begin{document}

\removeword\removeword{x1 x2 x3}

\end{document}
```

What can be done to have `stringstrings` remove the first two words?

**The intended use** (updated answer)

(If I should put that as separate question, I'll do)

I'm writing a description of a method, where the title of each section is formatted like `Step X: <step title>`. Now, I want to reference the section as `Step X ("<step title>")`. Currently, I'm using the solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73710/9075, which suggests to redefine `@currentlabelname`. However, I have to type my section name twice.

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{step}

\newcommand{\titleinquotes}[1]{(\enquote{\nameref{sec:#1}})}

\begin{document}

We will see something in Step~\ref{S1} \titleinquotes{S1}.

\refstepcounter{step}
\label{S1}
\section{Step \thestep: Setup Environment}
\label{sec:S1}

\end{document}
```

The question is how `\titleinquotes' has to be changed to have following output

> We will see something in Step 1 (“Setup Environment”)

The quick hack

```
\newcommand{\removedoubleword}[1]{\removeword[e]{#1} \removeword{\thestring}} 
\newcommand{\titleinquotes}[1]{(\enquote{\removedoubleword{\nameref{sec:#1}}})}
```

does not work: `Use of \\removeword doesn't match its definition.`. Without using `\nameref`, it works.

Comment: The example you show is not an example of what you *really* want. Can you add some more context? Removing a word from an explicitly given string is quite different from removing a word from something obtained with `\nameref`.

Comment: Also, it is not clear why you want to use `stringstrings`: if it is because you want to strip the "Step X:" part to reformat the title then why not take a more structured approach such as storing the step title as `\formatstep{X}{title}` and redefine `\formatstep` according to the two formats when using it in the two different contexts (section title and reference)? If you are interested in this approach I could attempt an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the `stringstring` documentation, you *cannot* directly nest its commands. Instead, `stringstring` manipulation commands provide a specific mechanism for composability: They store the result in `\thestring`, which *can* be used as input to subsequent commands. So you need two steps.

Most commands also "print out" the resulting `\thestring`. This can be supressed by passing the `[q]` (quiet) or `[e]` (encoded) option. The latter makes sure that special characters (such as `\$`) do not get expanded, which increases the robustness if `\thestring` is fed into another `stringstring` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\newcounter{step}

\begin{document}

  \removeword[e]{x1 x2 x3}
  \removeword{\thestring}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `[q]` you could also use the encode mode `[e]`. For convenience I would deine the follwoing command `\newcommand{\removedoubleword}[1]{\removeword[e]{#1} \removeword{\thestring}}`

Comment: @crixtox: I was just reading about encoded mode, which certainly should be used here. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I couldn't have said it better myself. [package author]